# System.Convert.ToSingle(value) always throws FormatException

Tags: c#, formatexception

I have several `strings` that I need to convert to `float`. When I try to do so, using `System.Convert.ToSingle(MyString)`, I always get a `FormatException`.

I have tried even creating strings like `"12.123"`, to make sure the numbers are okay, but again I got the exception. My question is, what is the correct format then? In what format should the number in string be?

Example of one of many strings I will convert: 50.105128

Comment: Works fine for me. Please add a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the problem.  Also, include the exception's message, as it may contain useful information as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be down to your system's culture which may be set to using a `,` as the separator. Setting the format to `InvariantCulture` will use a `.` for the separator.

```
Convert.ToSingle("12.123", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on culture, but you can use invariant in this way:

```
Convert.ToSingle("0", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert.ToSingle is culture-sensitive. In culture installed on your machine, decimal separator might be different from comma, and number may look like 50,105128

Use this overload instead, which allows to specify culture:

```
public static float ToSingle(
    Object value,
    IFormatProvider provider
)
```